# Read multiple array sent from Response::json in $.get() ajax - laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel-5.3

Please somebody guide me:

How to fetch data from:

```
Response::json(array('exam'=>$exam,'details'=>$details,'comment'=>$comment));
```

in blade using `$.get()` ajax method.

I'm stuck in this situation from last two days, not able to fetch multiple array data.

Thanks

Comment: You want to call an ajax() request from blade view and which is returning an multiple array and get the data from it?

Comment: ya..tht's true..I'm not able to read this multi-array data.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are not able to get the data from the response in your JS?

Comment: I can read data if it is single array data:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);     
  $.each(obj, function(key,value) {      
 $("#lblName").text(value.name); })                                                                 But, how to read data if data consists multiple arrays like 'exam', 'details', etc,.

Comment: Try my answer and fiddle and let me know if any further issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr = '[{"name":"Aman","age":20},{"name":"Ajay","age":22}]';

var data = JSON.parse(arr);

for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
  alert(data[i]["name"]);
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76qabk1a/8/)

Comment: I've tried it..it gives following error:                                                      Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 179
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Please check my code below: In controller.php->                                                   public function getExamDetails(){  ....                                                                response()->json(array('examDetails' => $examDetails, 'total_marks' => $total_marks, 'examQuestions' => $examQuestions));                                        }

Comment: in Index.blade.php, I'm writing following code to fetch data:                                   $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {    
   console.log(data);     
                  //success data      
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);                                                      });

Comment: In console tab data shows me 3 arrays:                                                          [{"name":"Demo Exam","type":"Exam","passing_percent":30,"duration":120,"start_date":"2015-11-21 06:34:00","end_date":"2020-12-31 06:34:00","negative_marking":"Yes","amount":null}][{"total_marks":"24.00"}][{"subject_id":1,"subject_name":"Physics"},{"subject_id":2,"subject_name":"Chemistry"},{"subject_id":3,"subject_name":"Maths"}]                                                      How to iterate through 'data' variable to fetch above info?

Comment: Ya..I've checked it..it throws Uncaught SyntaxError. In your fiddle ...there is one type of array having multiple values for name and age. But , in my case, there are three types of array, for [examDetails], [total_marks] and [examQuestions]. It parses 1st array examDetails nicely, but when it goes to '[' of 2nd array..it throws parser error.

Comment: Will you provide your array in the same fiddle given by me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134350/discussion-between-mayank-pandeyz-and-dipti-sheth).